# Windows mobile application and javascript communication

Tags: iphone, windows-mobile, mobile

Is it possible to create communication between running program context and javascript ? 
for example, iPhone have good example about it under webkit development on iPhone. 
It's possible to invoke this command `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` from webview in the application scope on Obj-C and iPhone platform. I'm looking to same thing in windows mobile 6 or greater versions.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/42203637-e509-4d9c-ba8b-2ed7b2989ea3) has some links about hosting a web browser control on an application.
I guess it's possible to catch events from the page, or maybe just from the url change that you can use to trigger an action on the application.

Comment: Hey Paulo, 
Thanks for your quick answer, but I'm looking for more then mouse or progress bar stuffs.

Comment: I didn't find better solution then what you advised.
Thank you Paulo.

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) has a WiMo prototype [here](http://github.com/hemisphire/phonegap-winmo/).  You have a web browser control in your application, then call out to C# by setting the href and intercepting in the Navigating event.